# One code is working while after a small change code is not working

Tags: c++

Question = leetcode question = 1047

[Remove All Adjacent Duplicates In String - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-all-adjacent-duplicates-in-string/description/)

> 1047. Remove All Adjacent Duplicates In String
>
> You are given a string `s` consisting of lowercase English letters. A **duplicate removal** consists of choosing two **adjacent** and **equal** letters and removing them.
>
> We repeatedly make **duplicate removals** on `s` until we no longer can.
>
> Return *the final string after all such duplicate removals have been made*. It can be proven that the answer is **unique**.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> **Input:** s = "abbaca"
> **Output:** "ca"
> **Explanation:**
> For example, in "abbaca" we could remove "bb" since the letters are adjacent and equal, and this is the only possible move.  The result of this move is that the string is "aaca", of which only "aa" is possible, so the final string is "ca".
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> **Input:** s = "azxxzy"
> **Output:** "ay"
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - `1 <= s.length <= 105`
> - `s` consists of lowercase English letters.

This code is working

```
class Solution {
public:
    string removeDuplicates(string s) {
        int n = s.length();
        string ans = "";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if((ans.length() > 0) && s[i] == ans[ans.length()-1]){
                ans.pop_back();
            }
            else{
                ans.push_back(s[i]);
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

after a small change in line no.7
`ans.length() > 0` to `ans.length() - 1 >= 0`
, code is not working

```
class Solution {
public:
    string removeDuplicates(string s) {
        int n = s.length();
        string ans = "";
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if((ans.length() - 1 >= 0) && s[i] == ans[ans.length()-1]){  // line no.7
                ans.pop_back();
            }
            else{
                ans.push_back(s[i]);
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

overflow error is showing. Why this is happening

Comment: Don't you have warning about `ans.length() - 1 >= 0` (signed/unsigned comparison)?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see what effects the small change has?

Comment: @Jarod42 did not get any warning

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: From msvc (also spot by gcc): *"warning C4296: '>=': expression is always true"* [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5KExzP1T6).

Comment: Try to increase warning level to let your compiler help to spot issue.

Comment: This is why we use version control software, like [git](https://git-scm.com/).

Comment: I mean, for any given small change on any code really, what's the chance that it wont...

Comment: `ans.length()` returns an `unsigned` type.    If `ans.length()` returns `0`, `ans.length() - 1` is neither zero nor negative.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Answer (score 5):

Because of `unsigned` integer (`length()`)

`ans.length() - 1 >= 0` is always `true`. (`0u - 1 == std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()`)

You might change to:

`ans.length() >= 1` or `!ans.empty()`.

You might avoid index completely with for-range and appropriate method:

```
std::string removeDuplicates(std::string& s) {
    std::string ans = "";
    for (auto c : s){
        if (!ans.empty() && c == ans.back()) {
            ans.pop_back();
        } else {
            ans.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```